# jxpath with collection as root

Tags: java, xpath

i have list of maps and want to get all maps with id = 2. when i wrap the list in a holder object, all works correctly (kotlin code):

```
class Holder(val value : Any)
val list = listOf(mapOf("id" to 2), mapOf("id" to 3))
val context = Holder(list)
val xpath = "value[id = 2]"
JXPathContext.newContext(context).iterate(xpath)
```

but when i try to get rid of the holder object:

```
val context = list
val xpath = "[id = 2]"
```

i get jxpath syntax error: `Invalid XPath`. how what's the correct syntax to work with collection as root object?

Comment: probably: `val xpath = "self::*[id = 2]"`

Comment: no exception this time but no element is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer. you can do it using `/.[id=2]` or `.[id=2]` syntax

Answer (score 1):

XML requires that there be a single root element, so XPath provides no way to select multiple root elements.

If you want to use XML, you'll have to wrap your collection of elements with a single root element.